# Cannot clone my bitbucket repository after doing a commit with a 3.6 GB bin file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I wanted to push a few changes to my bitbucket repository. However, I forgot to pull the updated version first as some changes were done to it by another team-member. I got an error with the push command (using Jenkin deploy) that I should pull the changes first. At this point I had executed the following commands:

```
git add some files 
git commit -m "commit message"
Jenkin deploy # here I got the error
```

After the error message, I pulled the updated version from the master branch using `git pull` which resulted in a conflict. I resolved the conflict with my version in Pycharm (IDE, in my use). The conflict was with a version number. After that, I did another commit (merge commit).

```
git commit
```

However, now I cannot enter the `src` folder in my bitbucket. Nothing happens when I click on `src` folder. I cannot clone my repository. I can open the rest of the folders. I get a 500 error when I try to open the commit **`e3895f0`** (in the below screenshot) which I executed before the pull command. For the rest of commits, I can open them. I can't figure this out. Either something is wrong on bitbucket side but I can open other folders or I broke something. Could it be that my commit was executed properly? As I ran git fsck and found one dangling blob item but not sure if that's going to help.

**Update 1:**
In this specific commit before the merge, I committed a new bin file with a size of 3.6 GB. Could that be a reason for this chaos?

**Update 2:** 
I reverted all the changes and went to back an older commit just before this problematic commit. Now I clone the repository with from that older commit, however, I am still unable to access src folder.

**Update 3:**
I did a hard reset by deleting all my commits since the problematic commit which solved the problem. Now I can access the src folder. I am aware that it's a dangerous approach, however, in this specific case, these new changes were not pulled by others.

```
git reset --hard thecommit-before-problematic-commit
git push -f
```

***However, the question still remains, how can I efficiently use this huge file in my repository without causing this problem again? It's a 3.6GB Google word2vec model.***

Here is my commit tree: The problematic commit can be seen in the screenshot (**`e3895f0`** ). [image]

Comment: Does that 500 page include a UUID?

Comment: @JimRedmond Nope, it just says something went wrong. I get the error when I try to go the commit e3895f0 in the screenshot. I updated the question the error message.

Comment: @engr_s I recommend you use feature branches in the future to avoid this problem. Good luck on the solution. I'll try to help out as much as possible with an answer

Comment: @Oxymoron okay, thanks. I will keep this in mind for the future. Just started using git so need some time to get a hang of it.

Comment: I'd contact their support team about this if I were you.

Comment: @Chris would do that tomorrow as I'll give it another try before contacting them.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to force commit all the files in this problematic directory?

Comment: `git` isn't intended to work well with binary files (especially large ones), and I'd definitely expect a 3.6Gb file to cause some trouble.

Comment: @TriskalJM realized that a bit too late. For now, I want to just recover access to src folder so I can open it. From that point on, I will look at other options for this bigger file such as git LFS (large file system).

Comment: I'd recommend viewing the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository

Comment: Assuming that you have a local copy of this commit… remove the giant binary blob (`git rm blob.bin`), amend the commit to delete it (`git commit --amend`) and then force-push (`git push --force`) it to your Bitbucket remote.

This should effectively cause Bitbucket to forget that the branch in question ever contained this giant binary blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a hard reset by deleting all my commits since the problematic commit which solved the problem. Now I can access the src folder. I am aware that it's a dangerous approach, however, in this specific case, these new changes were not pulled by others.

```
git reset --hard thecommit-before-problematic-commit
git push -f
```